# A little confusion over Sign up process in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am very new to PHP so i am trying this things differently to make my selft more proficient. 
Here i am trying to save data on to database but i couldn't bale to do so the data's are not saving in datbase during signup.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
$connection=mysqli_select_db("cinderella");
or die(mysqli_error($connection));
?>
```

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{          
   if($_POST['action']=="signup")
    {
        $name       = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['name']);
        $email      = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
        $password   = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);
    $phone   = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['phone']);
    $country   = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['country']);
    $city   = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['city']);
    $zip   = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['zip']);
        $query = "SELECT email FROM registration where email='".$email."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        $numResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) // Validate email address
        {
            $message =  "Invalid email address please type a valid email!!";
        }
        elseif($numResults>=1)
        {
            $message = $email." Email already exist!!";
        }
        else
        {
            mysql_query("insert into registration(name,email,password,phone,country,city,zip) values('".$name."','".$email."','".md5($password)."','".$phone."','".$country."','".$city."','".$zip."')");
            $message = "Signup Sucessfully!!";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

```
<html>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>


  <form action="php/sign.php" method="post" class="signup">
    <p><input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"></p>
    <p><input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email"></p>
    <p><input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
     <p><input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="phone"></p>
      <p><input id="country" name="country" type="text" placeholder="country"></p>
       <p><input id="city" name="city" type="text" placeholder="city"></p>
        <p><input id="zip" name="zip" type="text" placeholder="zip"></p>

    <input name="action" type="hidden" value="signup" /></p>
    <div>
                              <center>
                                  <span style="color:green;display:none;" class="sign-footer"><h4 style="margin-left: 0px;">Registered successfully .Please login  </h4></span>
                                  <span style="color:orange;display:none;" class="signerror-footer"><h4 style="margin-left: 0px;">Please check your email </h4></span>
                                </center>
                          </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Signup" /></p>
  </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

          var frm = $('.signup');
          frm.submit(function (ev) {
              $.ajax({
                  type: frm.attr('method'),
                  url: frm.attr('action'),
                  data: frm.serialize(),
                  success: function (data) {
            //alert(data);
                      if (data) {
                        //alert('data');
                        $('.sign-footer').css('display','block');
                      }
                      else{
                        $('.signerror-footer').css('display','block')
                      }
                  }
              });

              ev.preventDefault();
          });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Any help over this will help me a lot,.... Thank you ...*

Comment: what is your folder structure ?

Comment: i like the encoding on that password :))

Comment: @RanjeetSingh ... Ravi--> home.php ,config.php ....php--> sign.php , login.php ....

Comment: @madalinivascu thnk you.. any help over this.... will relaly be appreciated :)